# Rails sharebox tutorial - modifying asset structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am learning rails by creating this app, [Sharebox-tutorial](http://codyaray.com/downloads/2012/03/How-to-Build-a-Dropbox-like-Sharing-App-using-Ruby-on-Rails.html)
, and i am trying to figure out how to modify the asset structure diff from this tutorial.

This shows all the folders first, and then the uploaded files, as in dropbox. Can i get a hint or point me to a good resource, on how to show the folders and files together based on their last modified date (rather than separately), as in google drive.